# Having trouble with XCode: nullptr_t error

Tags: c++, xcode, geant4

I am new to XCode and doing my first project for a simulation software called Geant4. I have the below code in C++ and when I run it I keep getting this error:

```
error: member 'nullptr_t' declared as a template 
_LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR unique_ptr(nullptr_t) _NOEXCEPT : __ptr_(__value_init_tag(), __value_init_tag()) {}
```

The code below includes a CMakeLists.txt file and a sim.cc file. The issue seems to be coming from the sim.cc file. I did some reading and it seems to be an issue with my version of XCode (14.3). I tried adding the path to iostream but that did not fix the issue.

Does anyone have any recommendations about how to fix this problem?

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16...3.21 FATAL_ERROR)

project(Simulation)

find_package(Geant4 REQUIRED ui_all vis_all)

include(${Geant4_USE_FILE})

file(GLOB sources ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/*.cc)
file(GLOB headers ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/*.hh)

add_executable(sim sim.cc ${sources} ${headers})
target_link_libraries(sim ${Geant4_LIBRARIES})

add_custom_target(Simulation DEPENDS sim)
```

sim.cc

```
#include <iostream>

#include "G4RunManager.hh"
#include "G4UImanager.hh"
#include "G4VisManager.hh"
#include "G4VisExecutive.hh"
#include "G4UIExecutive.hh"

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    G4RunManager *runManager = new G4RunManager();
    
    G4UIExecutive *ui = new G4UIExecutive(argc, argv);
    
    G4VisManager *visManager = new G4VisExecutive();
    visManager->Initialize();
    
    G4UImanager *UImanager = G4UImanager::GetUIpointer();
    
    ui->SessionStart();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you including two different versions of iostream? The first version is very strange, I would try just removing it.

Comment: [Compiles for me](https://wandbox.org/permlink/kSo1C3qaEFWQTQTW).  What command line flags is Xcode passing to the compiler?  (And what version of the compiler is it using?)

Comment: Actually it's not obvious why you need to include iostream at all, since your code is not using this header.

Comment: Why are you using `new` all over main? Not needed AND you do not delete anything. Just make pointerless instances. If you ever think you really need to `new` then use `std::make_unique/std::unique_ptr` to avoid a lot of memory managment bugs

Comment: I don't know about XCode but normally compilers print the file and line number with each error message. It would be helpful to see those in this case.

Comment: @PepijnKramer Strangely the error message appears to be generated by one of the constructors of `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: I think you need to unlearn a bunch of Java. Outside of punctuation and a few keywords, C++ and Java are *very* different.

Comment: @john It is probably pulled in as a result of iostream somewhere. Unique_ptr is useful in library development too ;)

Comment: Note that Apple's compiler uses C++98 by default. `nullptr_t` was added in C++11; Geant requires C++17.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I successfully reinstalled Geant4 following these [instructions](http://geant4-dna.in2p3.fr/styled-6/styled-12/index.html). There seemed to be a compiler issue and Geant4 did not have the correct file paths. The sample code above now runs with no changes to the code.